# When and how do mineral chelates separate in the body?

Tags: biochemistry, amino-acids, minerals, absorption

If one consumes an amino acid chelate such as iron bisglycinate, it is generally absorbed intact as far as I am aware. At some point, presumably the iron could be used for say hemoglobin synthesis and the glycine for collagen synthesis. How exactly does the dissociation of this chelate occur in the body to support this?

Comment: I have no idea of the specifics here, but every ion and its ligand have an equillibrium.

Comment: Better in Biology SE perhaps